# On GitHub, allow approving your own PR without allowing pushing to main branch

Tags: github, configuration, branch, pull-request

I'm trying to configure a GitHub project with the following properties:

1. All users - including admins - are required to submit code to `main` via a pull request, and cannot push directly to `main`
2. All users - including admins - must wait for all CI tests to pass before merging a pull request
3. All users must have their pull requests approved *but* admins may bypass this requirement and merge their own pull requests

I'm having trouble satisfying both the first and third requirements at the same time. Specifically, if I enable the "Do not allow bypassing the above settings" setting, then there's no way for admins to bypass pull request approval. However, if I disable it, then admins are able to push directly to `main`. Is there any way I can have my cake and eat it too?

Here are my full branch protection settings for the `main` branch:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could disable "Require approvals", then use a GitHub Actions workflow and the GitHub API to check if one of these two conditions is true:

- the PR author is a repo admin
- there is a PR approval

and make the outcome a required check.

Using the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli), you get the [permission level](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/collaborators/collaborators#get-repository-permissions-for-a-user) of a user `$user` with

```bash
gh api "repos/{owner}/{repo}/collaborators/$user/permission" --jq '.permission'
```

Checking PR approvals is a bit more complicated because without required approvals, the `reviewDecision` field in the PR object isn't populated any longer. Instead, we have to look at the array of reviews, and determine if at least one reviewer's most recent non-comment review was an approval.

For the review with ID `$id`, this would look like this:

```bash
gh pr view "$id" --json reviews --jq '
    .reviews
    | map(select(.state != "COMMENTED"))
    | reduce .[] as $item ({}; . + {($item.author.login): $item.state})
    | to_entries
    | map(select(.value == "APPROVED"))
    | length > 0
'
```

This returns `true` if there is a least one approval.

A workflow using these two checks would have to be triggered when a pull request is opened, and when a review is submitted; additionally, synchronizing a PR might dismiss a review, so that should also be a trigger.

Pull request triggers can filter by base branch, but reviews cannot, so we have to add this condition separately.

As a final obstacle, having multiple triggers (`pull_request` and `pull_request_review`) results in multiple status checks, and we can't make them both required; for a PR created by a non-admin, the `pull_request` check  still fails when the `pull_request_review` check passes:

[image: Multiple checks]

To this end, the workflow creates a separate third [check](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses#create-a-commit-status), which is the one we have to use in the branch protection rule. For a PR branch with the most recent commit hash `$sha` and outcome `$state`, the GitHub CLI command to set the status looks like

```bash
gh api "repos/{owner}/{repo}/statuses/$sha" \
    -f "state=$state" -f context='Non-admin PR approval'
```

For additional information, a URL can be added, as in the workflow below. The required check can be found under "Non-admin PR approval".

[image]

The workflow continues even if a condition isn't met, but the step checking PR approvals is skipped if the first step determined that the author is an admin. The overall result is communicated using the `STATE` environment variable, which is used in the final step to set the status.

```yaml
name: Check PR approval for non-admin authors

on:
  # PR into main opened, reopened, or synchronized
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

  # When a review is submitted
  pull_request_review:
    types:
      - submitted

jobs:
  checkapproval:
    name: Check PR approval

    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    # Event has to be a pull request, or the base branch has to be main
    if: >-
      github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        || github.event.pull_request.base.ref == 'main'

    steps:
      - name: Check if author is repo admin
        env:
          author: ${{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}
          repo: ${{ github.repository }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: |
          perm=$(gh api "repos/$repo/collaborators/$author/permission" \
              --jq '.permission')

          if [[ $perm != 'admin' ]]; then
              echo "Author is not admin; approval required" >&2
          else
              echo "Author is admin; no approval required" >&2

              # Set success state in environment
              echo "STATE=success" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          fi

      - name: Check for PR approval
        # Run only if the previous step failed
        if: env.STATE != 'success'
        env:
          prid: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: |
          approved=$(gh pr view "$prid" --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" \
              --json reviews --jq '
                  .reviews
                  | map(select(.state != "COMMENTED"))
                  | reduce .[] as $item (
                      {}; . + {($item.author.login): $item.state}
                  )
                  | to_entries
                  | map(select(.value == "APPROVED"))
                  | length > 0
              ')

          if [[ $approved != 'true' ]]; then
              echo "No PR approval found" >&2

              # Set failure state in environment
              echo "STATE=failure" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
              exit 0
          fi

          echo "PR approval found" >&2

          # Set success state in environment
          echo "STATE=success" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

      - name: Set result in separate status
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
          sha: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
          repo: ${{ github.repository }}
          id: ${{ github.run_id }}
        run: |
          gh api "repos/$repo/statuses/$sha" \
              --raw-field state="$STATE" \
              --raw-field context='Non-admin PR approval' \
              --raw-field target_url="https://github.com/$repo/actions/runs/$id"
```